# How to log details in php xml file for Twilio sms response

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I have implemented Twilio SMS response from [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCxh5EcwmEs)  (its just one minute video)
This works for all the cases but if I receive a text from Google Pixel I am not able to respond
I am storing all the SMS response into the database but I am not able to store the ones coming from Google Pixel.

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
include "config.php";
require __DIR__ . '/Twilio/autoload.php';// Loads the library

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO sms (MessageSid, smsFrom, smsTo, Body, timeStamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $MessageSid, $FromNumber, $ToNumber, $body, $timeStamp);


$FromNumber = isset($_POST['From']) ? $_POST['From'] : '0';
$body = isset($_POST['Body']) ? $_POST['Body'] : '0';
$MessageSid = isset($_POST['MessageSid']) ? $_POST['MessageSid'] : '0';
$ToNumber = isset($_POST['To']) ? $_POST['To'] : '0';
$timeStamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$con->close();
?>
```

What twilio does is they will allow us a web-hook and we can get the response.
I can see SMS in their logs and my web-hook is executed successfully but there is nothing stored in our DB.
any ideas on how to debug it? I tried sending emails with all the values but it throws me an error as this is an xml file.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! It's not just about security. If any of the posted values contains, for example, a single quote or ends with a backslash, your query will fail.

Comment: You should also check your web servers error log to see if there's any error messages.

Comment: I checked Web server logs, Php error logs but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Then I'll recommend that you fix what's mentioned in the first comment and see if it works better after that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have updated my code. Still that issue exists

Comment: Add some [error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for your query and check if you see anything. Other than that, it's pretty hard for us to know what could be wrong. Do some debugging, like logging the requests (to file) and see if you get a request as expected and what the request contains.

Comment: Try setting the variables you're using in bind_param *before* you call bind_param.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - `bind_param()` sets them as references so the order doesn't matter. Even the examples [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) sets them after.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Aha, my old C programming ways come back to bite me :) Thanks for setting me on the straight and narrow!